# Can I download and run javascript and be in compliance with Android policy?

Tags: android

Apple's guidelines allows for downloading and running javascript in JavascriptCore and UIWebView/WKebView.

What about Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple aspects which you need to pay attention to:

1. Is the JavaScript code trusted? For example, if you load your own script from a SSL secured site and properly check the certificate, we can consider it "trusted code". If you download arbitrary code or don't use proper security while downloading, we have to assume that the code is harmful and/or modified. In terms of VMs (e.g. JAVA, Dalvik, ART), we call this "untrusted code".
2. Does the code have access to elevated permissions? For example, simply including JavaScript in a `WebView` does not expose the device to serious dangers. However, two situations can create security problems:

   1. Running the code outside of a `WebView` in a script engine which does not provide sandboxing as the `WebView` does.
   2. Running the code inside a `WebView` but with access to APIs which expose usually unavailable resources ([see documentation for examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)).

The Android guidelines [discourage developers from running any Android code which is not included in the APK](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#DynamicCode):

> We strongly discourage loading code from outside of your application
>   APK. Doing so significantly increases the likelihood of application
>   compromise due to code injection or code tampering. It also adds
>   complexity around version management and application testing. Finally,
>   it can make it impossible to verify the behavior of an application, so
>   it may be prohibited in some environments.
>
> If your application does dynamically load code, the most important
>   thing to keep in mind about dynamically loaded code is that it runs
>   with the same security permissions as the application APK. The user
>   made a decision to install your application based on your identity,
>   and they are expecting that you provide any code run within the
>   application, including code that is dynamically loaded.

And, as I already mentioned in #1, if you actually load code, it should come from a trusted source:

> The major security risk associated with dynamically loading code is
>   that the code needs to come from a verifiable source. If the modules
>   are included directly within your APK, then they cannot be modified by
>   other applications. This is true whether the code is a native library
>   or a class being loaded using DexClassLoader. We have seen many
>   instances of applications attempting to load code from insecure
>   locations, such as downloaded from the network over unencrypted
>   protocols or from world writable locations such as external storage.
>   These locations could allow someone on the network to modify the
>   content in transit, or another application on a users device to modify
>   the content on the device, respectively.

They [forbid running any untrusted Android code](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityManager.html):

> Untrusted code cannot be safely isolated within the Dalvik VM.

However, the first document is not precise about its intention. Although it refers to "code" in general, it really means Android bytecode and native executable code. The second document is a little more clear, let me emphasize the important part:

> Untrusted code cannot be safely isolated **within the Dalvik VM**.

Actually, JavaScript is executed by a script engine which is part of the Dalvik (or ART) VM. The script engine provides a sandbox in which the JavaScript code is executed. For example, in a regular `WebView`, JavaScript code has the same permissions as that on any website. You can restrict and/or extend those permissions.

Long story short: Even if the code was untrusted, a `WebView` or a properly configured script engine does provide a sufficient sandboxed environment. However, it is still far better to only load trusted code from a secure origin.

If Android had forbidden the execution of arbitrary JavaScript code, 99% of Android browsers would violate this rule ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes. You can. You are very much allowed to do this.

You should consider using an AsyncTask to download the javascript, if you cannot put it directly in the HTML ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html )